# Long term effects and impact of masturbation

Tags: sex, masturbation

So, I'm bringing a kind of sensitive topic to here. Usually there are lots of articles on the web saying that masturbation is a good stress-relief mechanism and that it can avoid some kinds of prostate cancer and some other good things.

However  based on my own experience (and some friends too) long term masturbation doesn't seem to be that good at all. From my personal case I can say if I masturbate 2 or 3 times a day and keep it for more than a week I feel the following:

- I'm always tired and lack energy;
- I work less efficiently;
- I have a shorter temper, don't really have head to deal with anything;
- Always bored;
- It no longer gives me pleasure; Ruins my sexual life;
- Lack of sexual desire;
- More passive than active behavior;
- No longer have self-discipline;
- Completely drained.

Why does this happen, is there any specific research on this subject?

Does this happen because I'm stimulating way too much the "reward"-center of the brain *or* because in the process of the ejaculation I'm taking a lot of proteins and chemicals out of my body that need to be produced / acquired again?

Are there any long terms effects of this one might experience?

**Note**: I actually stopped masturbating on my freshman years when I had issues getting achieving an erection. After few weeks everything was normal again.

Comment: Are you actually only asking about masturbation or about ejaculation in general? None of what you write seems to be unique to masturbation as opposed to a lot of sex (and 2 to 3 times a day is *a lot* more than the average for that)

Comment: @YviDe I never felt in the exact same way with a lot of sex. So I guess it's better to keep up about masturbation.

Comment: In order to reduce prostate cancer risk, once a week should be enough. 
But maybe you should get another hobby ;-).

Comment: [Also strongly related](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/11687/8212)