# Does frequent masturbation decrease testosterone levels in men?

Tags: masturbation, testosterone

I'm just curious. Done no research into this. Can anyone explain if there is a correlation?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE.  Part of the rules of Stack Exchange include demonstrating what you've learned trying to answer your own question and formulate a question based on where you're stumped.  This rule is no different from basically all SE sites, including StackOverflow, so I'm not sure why you would choose not to put any effort into it on Health SE. ESPECIALLY because it's in Beta we try to be vigilant about quality control. Downvoted for effort; please at least Google it before editing your question, then I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Also, what prompted you to think there was an association?

Comment: @DoctorWhom Short questions tend to get short answers....

Comment: @DoctorWhom Yes I see how that would be useful for SO community to prevent people asking questions like "how do I make Facebook?".  In my opinion, other SE sites should loosen up the rules a little. It can be very intimidating asking the question that would satisfy all the guidelines. This is a QnA site after all, I come here to exercise my curiosity and ask questions. Instead get flagged and down voted. It is quite off-putting, because the whole community seems to be very snobby instead of welcoming. (In my personal experience)

Comment: I get how you feel, and felt the same way at the beginning. I started on other SE sites.  But Health isn't a typical Q&A site. If you scroll through the questions history you'll see numerous questions that are unanswerable for a variety of reasons, or repeatedly-duplicated (didn't look for previous SE answers first), unfounded (didn't try to read first), and "diagnose this."  Trying to establish standards means asking participants to put in effort.  Otherwise we have lots of questions without answers, diluting the pool, discouraging those who might answer questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No, [masturbation does not decrease testosterone levels in the blood](http://www.testofuel.com/tf/does-masturbating-lower-testosterone/).

---

Relevant studies cited in the linked article:

Fox CA, Ismail AAA, Love DN, Kirkham KE, Loraine JA. Studies on the relationship between plasma testosterone levels and human sexual activity. J Endocrinol. 1972;52:51–58.

Batty J. Acute changes in plasma testosterone levels and their relation to measures of sexual behaviour in the male house mouse (Mus musculus) Anim. Behav. 1978;26:349–357.

Phoenix CH, Dixson AF, Resko JA. Effects of ejaculation on levels of testosterone, cortisol, and luteinizing hormone in peripheral plasma of rhesus monkeys. J Comp Physiol Psychol. 1977;91:120–127.

Comment: Why is it that frequent masturbation reduces the ability to maturbate?

Comment: @Sonevol I don't quite see how this is related to my answer or the question. [Self-advertising my own answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/11687/8212) and [advertising Chris' answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/11676/8212) on a similar topic. This might provide you with some information. Afterwards, feel free to ask a new question on Health.SE (taking account of the Community guidelines layed out during the tour)!